# Azure .NET MVC Core Application: User not being redirected upon form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I am writing a barebones Azure .NET MVC Core Application in which once a user presses the submit button on a form, that user is redirected to Facebook. However, when the user presses the form's submit button, that user simply gets refreshed instead of being directed towards Facebook. Below is my code:

**/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
@RenderBody()
@using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAssignmentController", "TestForm", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <label>Test Form</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**/Models/RoleAssignmentRecord.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AccessChangeMonitoringUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AccessChangeMonitoringUI.Controllers
{
    public class RoleAssignmentController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult TestForm()
        {
            return Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not 100% on this but I'm guessing the GET is throwing things off here. It's typical to have <form> do a POST, and I'm guessing the browser is getting hung up on this part. Try changing to POST and see where it gets you?

Comment: Changed to POST and unfortunately, the redirect still does not work

Comment: @HenryZhu- I don't see any problem with your code and i am replicating the exact code which you have posted at my end and i am able to redirect.do you mind clearing the cache and restarting your solution and then give it a try ? Can you let us know, are you on any VPN and if facebook is allowed to be connected from your network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debug your codes to see if it can trigger the TestForm action? It seems that the first parameter should be actionName and the second should be controllerName.

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, FormMethod method);
```

The form should like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestForm", "RoleAssignment", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <label>Test Form</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```